# Is there any way to secure Esp32 BLE server?

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, bluetooth, ble, security

I've got a project in which currently I am using Bluetooth classic (with SSP - Simple secure pairing) to communicate to my esp32 board with my android app, but Bluetooth classic serial communication is not supported on ios devices therefore I want to switch to using BLE instead, but **I can't find any way to secure the BLE that will ship with the product**!

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks :)

Comment: you could use higher level routines like digest, shared secret, public key, etc.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit, I didn't understand. Thanks for helping :)